# Unable to Navigate to Other Screens After Logging In Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, material3

After logging in to the Flutter app, I am redirected to the home screen, but I'm unable to navigate to other screens such as Messages or Profile. The navigation bar appears correctly, but when I tap on other navigation items, the respective screens don't render. However, when I restart the app, the issue disappears temporarily, only to reappear upon logging in again.

I've checked the code, and it seems that the navigation logic is correctly implemented. When debugging, I found that the correct screens are returned from the _buildHome method in main.dart. However, the screens don't render on the UI. Upon logging in, I expect to be able to navigate to different screens smoothly without any issues.

Here are the relevant parts of the code:

**main.dart**

```
Future main() async {
  runApp(
    MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => SettingsProvider()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => UserProvider()),
      ],
      child: MainApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class MainApp extends StatelessWidget {
  MainApp({super.key});

  final ThemeData lightTheme = ThemeData(
    colorScheme: lightColorScheme,
    useMaterial3: true,
  );

  final ThemeData darkTheme = ThemeData(
    colorScheme: darkColorScheme,
    useMaterial3: true,
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var settingsProvider = Provider.of<SettingsProvider>(context);
    var userProvider = Provider.of<UserProvider>(context);

    bool isUserLoggedIn = userProvider.isLoggedIn();

    return MaterialApp(
        theme: settingsProvider.isDarkMode ? darkTheme : lightTheme,
        home: isUserLoggedIn
            ? _buildHome(settingsProvider.currentPageIndex)
            : const LoginScreen(),
        routes: {
          '/login': (context) => const LoginScreen(),
          '/register': (context) => const RegisterScreen(),
          '/home': (context) => const HomeScreen(),
          '/profile': (context) => const MyProfileScreen(),
          '/messages': (context) => const MessagesScreen(),
          '/chat': (context) => const ChatScreen(),
        });
  }

  Widget _buildHome(int currentPageIndex) {
    switch (currentPageIndex) {
      case 0:
        return const HomeScreen();
      case 1:
        return const MessagesScreen();
      case 2:
        return const MyProfileScreen();
      default:
        return const HomeScreen();
    }
  }
}
```

**LoginScreen.dart** loginFunc

```
Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
  return const HomeScreen();
}), (route) => false);
```

**UserProvider.dart** - it's working right

```
bool isLoggedIn() {
  return _user.token.isNotEmpty;
}
```

**InNavigationBar.dart**

```
class InNavigationBar extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  const InNavigationBar({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var settingsProvider = Provider.of<SettingsProvider>(context);

    return NavigationBar(
      onDestinationSelected: (int index) {
        settingsProvider.setCurrentPageIndex(index);
      },
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.surfaceVariant,
      indicatorColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
      selectedIndex: settingsProvider.currentPageIndex,
      destinations: const <Widget>[
        NavigationDestination(
          selectedIcon: Icon(Icons.home),
          icon: Icon(Icons.home_outlined),
          label: 'Üyeler',
        ),
        NavigationDestination(
          icon: Badge(
            label: Text('2'),
            child: Icon(Icons.messenger_sharp),
          ),
          label: 'Mesajlar',
        ),
        NavigationDestination(
          icon: Icon(Icons.person_2),
          label: 'Profil',
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  Size get preferredSize => const Size.fromHeight(kBottomNavigationBarHeight);
}
```